# Android Studio on Non-English Windows System: Local number format during design

Tags: android, android-studio

I am using Hindi language Windows 10 PC for android development. It started giving me problem due to that and I am searching and fixing all one by one. Latest is that when I change any value inside a constraint layout it will be written in design XML file in Hindi language number format. Below is the screen shot of it:
[image: Hindi number in Android Studio XML file]

Currently I am manually changing it to English language numbers. Is there any setting for that? Please let me know if any face and fixed similar issue.

Comment: Did you solve your problem ?

Comment: Yes, I found a work around for that. I was doing it in React-Native project and added this in project level gradle.properties file: org.gradle.jvmargs=-Duser.country=US -Duser.language=en